# Mercurial to Manage Existing Website?

Tags: mercurial

Getting ready to launch a website/project that was in beta testing. I want to switch it over to version control (Mercurial since I'm familiar with it).

Problem is, I am not sure how to go about doing it since the code on the website is already up and in-use and how to deal with the directories I do not need to manage (vendor and web/Upload).

Whats the best way to go about this?

Would I put the entire site into a folder, init a Merc repo, use hgignore to not track vendor and web/Upload, commit, then clone it to the live server?

Thanks! Just confused on what to do since the site is live and has user uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to turn the website directory on your web server into a Mercurial repository.  If that's the case, you would create a new repository somewhere on that computer, then move the .hg directory in the new repository into the website directory you want to be the root of the repository.  You should then be able to run

```
hg add * --exclude vendor --exclude web/Upload
hg commit -m "Adding site to version control."
```

to get all the non-user files into version control.

I recommend, however, that you write a script or investigate tools that will deploy your website out of a repository outside your web root.  You don't want your .hg directory exposed to the world.  Until you get a deploy script/tool working, make sure you tell your webserver to prohibit/reject all requests to your .hg directory.

Comment: Alright, so I'm clear... I will init the repository on the website's server, add the file and commit and I should be fine? Thanks!